# JIT optimizer for C/C++

Tags: c++, c, optimization, branch, jit

I was reading about the advantages of JIT over precompiled and one of those mentioned was that a JIT could adjust branch predictions based on actual runtime data.  Now it's been a long time since I wrote a compiler in college, but it seems to me that something similar can be achieved for precompiled code also in most cases (where there are no explicit gotos).

Consider the following code:

```
   test x
   jne L2:
L1: ...
   jmp L3:
L2: ...
L3:
```

If we have some runtime instrumentation that sees how many times the 'jne L2' is true, it could physically swap all the instructions in the L1: block and the L2: block.  Of course, it would have to know that no thread is within either block during the swap, but those are details...

```
   test x
   jeq L1:
L2: ...
   jmp L3:
L1: ...
L3:
```

I understand there are also issues when the program code is loaded in readonly memory, etc. but it's an idea.

So my question is, is such a JIT optimization feasible for C/C++ or am I missing some fundamental reason why this cannot be done?  Are there any JIT optimizers for C/C++ out there?

Comment: Questions require a question mark somewhere in your sentences. What is the problem you face, exactly?

Comment: Edited the original post.  No problem, just wondering.

Comment: I don't get the "no explicit goto" part.  You're talking about jump instructions.  What's the difference?

Comment: I meant that there are no explicit gotos in the source that jump directly into the 'then' or 'else' block from somewhere else in the code, i.e. from outside the conditional statement.

Comment: @Jay - Ah.  In such a case I would expect the JIT to patch those references too, otherwise it's doing a pretty half-assed job.  :P

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Most modern CPU support branch prediction.  They have a small cache which allow the CPU to notionally give you the benefits of re-ordering at runtime.  This cache is fairly limited in size, but may mean you don't get as much benefit as you might imagine.  Some CPUs can even start executing both branches and discard the work done on the branch not taken.

---

EDIT: The biggest advantage in using a JIT compiler comes from code like this.

```
if (debug) {
   // do something
}
```

JITs are very good at detecting and optimising code which doesn't do anything. (If you have a micro-benchmark which suggests Java is much faster than C it is most likely the JIT has detected your test isn't doing anything where the C compiler didn't)

You might ask, why doesn't C have something like this? Because it has something "better"

```
#if DEBUG
    // do something
#endif
```

This is optimal provided DEBUG rarely changes and you have very few of these flags so you can compile every useful combination.

The problem this approach is scalability. Every flag you add can double the number of pre-compiled binaries to produce.

If you have many such flags and it is impractical to compile every combination, you need to rely on branch prediction to optimise your code dynamically.

Comment: So it's like taking both roads in *The Road Not Taken*? That's cheating!

Comment: @muntoo, and be very complicated. The branch not taken could trigger an interrupt and is quite common! e.g. `double d = p == NULL ? NAN : *p` It is limited for obvious reasons which is why it is still a small advantage in doing the optimisation in a JIT.

Comment: OK, I had thought the parallel pipelines would start the work of fetching the operands and whatnot but, by the time either pipeline reaches the execution stage, you would know which branch was taken and only the 'true' pipeline would proceed to execution.  Of course, one of the operands in the 'false' branch could be an indirect address and trigger a fault as you said.

Answer (score 8):

There is no JIT compiler for C++ that I am aware of; however, GCC does support feedback directed optimization (FDO), which can use runtime profiling to optimize branch prediction and the like.

See the [GCC options](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Optimize-Options.html) starting with "-fprofile" (HINT: "-fprofile-use" uses the generated runtime profile to perform the optimization, while "-fprofile-generate" is used to generate the runtime profile).

Comment: Sure, but the profile-based optimization is only as good as the profiling data was representative.  The proponents of JIT claim (rightly so) that their optimizations are for that particular run, not some profiled data that may or may not have relevance to the actual run taking place.

Comment: @Jay: JIT has the same problem, just at a smaller granularity: it can only optimise for the data that has already been processed in the current run, which may or may not be representative of the data still to come.

Answer (score 1):

You are refering to tracing or reoptimizing JITs, not just any old JIT, something like this hasn't been made for C or C++ (at least not publically). However, you might want to check if LLVM isn't headed that way with a branch (considering its both a compiler and JIT) using Clang or GCC front ends, as I've seem some topics suggesting it might be implemented.

Comment: Yes, it would have to be a coopertive effort between the compiler and a runtime JIT to mark which then/else blocks are self-contained (i.e. have no external references) and can be safely relocated in memory.  I understand Michael's comment about multi-pipelined architectures that obviate the need for this optimization -- modulo cache limitations -- so maybe that's the reason no one has pursued this.

Comment: Sorry, I meant Peter in the above comment.

Comment: @jay: branch prediction can only solve so much, thats why tracing JIT's where created in the first place

Comment: I am unsure about the necessity of involving the front-end in the development. I think LLVM could get away with re-optimizing the IR on the run (after all, it was created with JIT in mind).

Comment: @Matthieu M. I only mentioned the front-ends to involve the C & C++ languages (seeing as LLVM isn't not language specific)

Answer (score 0):

The HP Dynamo binary recompiler demonstrated that it is possible to achieve speed-ups of up to 20 % on optimized code produced by a C++ compiler.  Dynamo isn't exactly a JIT compiler since it starts with arbitrary machine code instead of some higher level representation such as JVM bytecode or .NET CIL, but in principle a JIT for C++ could only be more efficient than Dynamo.  See: http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/summary?doi=10.1.1.12.7138&rank=1

Dynamo was created for the HP PA-RISC architecture, and never offered as a commercial product, so it isn't of much use in the current world dominated by x86 variants.  I wonder if VMware, Connectix or Parallels have ever played around with adding optimization passes to their recompilers, or have they already got rid of binary translation in favour of the virtualization features in the latest x86 CPUs.

Comment: 20% is huge!  It seems to me the C++ community has gotten complacent over speed, while C# and Java work inexorably to close the gap.  Perhaps the growth of native apps on smartphones will provide the needed push to squeeze out more performance.

Comment: @Jay: I would not say complacent. Each new release of gcc or clang show speed improvements. However it is true that such improvements are usually limited to compile-time... The problem is that any time of code modification (at runtime) necessarily adds some complexity, you need to measure, embed a code generator, etc... while C and C++ aim at producing small and efficient code.

Comment: A trace-based dynamic optimizer like Dynamo can easily optimize over library boundaries, which gives it an inherent advantage.  GCC has recently introduced support for link-time optimization, which helps for statically linked binaries, but I don't think it would even make sense to do LTO for dynamically linked libraries.